# Editing questions that include the tag in the title?

Tags: discussion, editing

Is it wise to edit the title of questions if they include the (only) relevant tag?

- [Geometry nodes. How to Separate mesh islands by the largest island?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279102/)
- [Arc Between Edge Endpoints Using Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278657/)
- [How can I make horizontal plane instances attached to branches using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278699/)

Or other questions where this is not explicitly the case, but where no other conclusion is possible that they must be [geometry-nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry-nodes) because of the already existing tag:

- [How to base point selection on a distance in a certain direction in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279096/)
- [Rotate instances to face one object with Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278844/)
- [Relax vertices in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278619/)

Should these questions/titles be edited for clarity or not?

Comment: I think that many users ignore the tag system, so I am of the opinion that if it is already in place and the edit adds no other value, then I would probably leave it alone in most cases. Newer users don't know how SE works, and how questions are  typically formatted. Because of this, one word edits may discourage participation because they think they did something wrong. In general though, tags alone should provide this information rather than the title.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks for your comment! You mean that other users who might be able to answer the question ignore these tags? Because the questioner already knows that they are Geometry Nodes. It might be wise to edit these titles anyway, just to push the tag system a bit, wouldn't it?

Comment: Having the "tags" mentioned in the title isn't necessarily bad. I understand they may be redundant, but on the other hand they speed things up by making the title clearer and self contained. It is easier to just read a title that mention them, than having to also go for the "small print" for tags, for example when skimming through the question list .

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yeap and if you are not a Stack user just looking for an answer to a similar question, is easy to just read the title, because you don't know how the site works.

Comment: @Emir But only if you were to browse all questions without noticing the tags. For searching it doesn't matter whether it's mentioned in the title.